# search any word inside a string in million rows

Tags: sql, algorithm

I have a set of 50k values say X. each value i want to compare with a set of 10k values say Y. if X is present any where in the string Y it matches.

So each value in X i want to check across each value in Y and assign X if it matches.

what would be the best method to complete this task. It is required for a data mining project.

I loaded the data into MS Access database.
then using a vba program 
  take each X . Update Y if it matches (Like '%X%') but it is a never ending process. The columns are indexed but no effect.

Is there any algorithm or steps to reduce it into step-by-step process and complete the mapping faster?

Please let me know if there is any other options available other than the answers given below. I ll explain the scenario bit more

**Table1.Data**

```
sentense1
sentense2
sentense3
sentense4
sentense5
sentense6
-
-
-
Sentense100k
```

**Table2.Phrase  (Means multiple words)**

```
Phrase1
Phrase2
Phrase3
Phrase4
Phrase5
-
-
-
Phrase 100k
```

Want to check `Phrase1` has any Match in `Sentense1 to Sentense100k` Exact Match of Phrase, anywhere Match of Phrase, Maximum Words in Phrase1 Match in Sentense etc.. and create a map based on best Match(ideally exact phrase available anywhere in the sentense)

**Table3 Output**

```
   Data                    Best Possible Phrase    Second Best Phrase(Optional)
    Sentense1               Phrase1000             Phrase50k 
    Sentense2               Phrase10               Phrase70k
```

Please let me know any tool,logic to perform this. The logic what i tried in SQL
1.

```
Select A.Data,B.Phrase from Table1 A left join Table2 B on A.Data Like '%' + B.Phrase + '%'
```

2.

Check for any word in phrase available in sentense. So replaced all spaces with % like word1%word2%word3. then did query as

```
A.Data Like '%' + B.Phrase + '%' which is
A.Data Like '%word1%word2%word3%'
```

But it takes days to complete the task for this much data.

Any readily usable tools, indexing methods,queries would really help. The answers given below seems too technical for me to adapt. Please guide

Comment: Hey, do you need to code that by hand? This seems like a problem for http://spark.apache.org/ and friends which are designed to do exactly those kind of operations in a very quick and distributed way.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a suffix tree in linear time (you can look up suffix trees online), out of the concatenation of all strings in X and Y, with special unique symbols that end each string.

Then for each string Xi in X, you look it up in the suffix tree (linear time in length of Xi) and assign Xi to each string in Y that is somewhere in the subtree rooted at the end of Xi.

This is linear time in the number of strings in Y that Xi is assigned to.

Thus you get an optimal O(N + k) time algorithm, where:

- N is the total length of all the strings in X and Y,
- and k is the total number of matches between query strings in X and target strings in Y.